# How to place modal in the bottom right of the page with fluent kit?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fluent-kit

I use [fluent-kit](https://nespero.com/fluent/jquery/docs/motion/modal/) package and I want to place the modal window in a bottom right corner of the page. I add `.modal-bottom` and `.modal-right` classes to the `div.modal-dialog` element, as per [modal#position docs](https://nespero.com/fluent/jquery/docs/motion/modal/#position), however, it doesn't work.

My **HTML**

```
<div class='modal fade' id='modal-example' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='modal-example-title' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-right modal-bottom' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <h5 class='modal-title' id='modal-example-title'>TITLE</h5>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
          <span aria-hidden='true' class='mi mi-Close'></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do want to use this package specifically as it provides this functionality out of the box (I can see working examples in the docs). I am 100% sure my scripts and styles are added correctly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all the fluent-kit modal functionality is enclosed in `.fluent-modal` namespace.

In order to all the **position** classes:

- `.modal-top`
- `.modal-bottom`
- `.modal-left`
- `.modal-right`

and extra **size** classes:

- `.modal-full-height`
- `.modal-fluid`

to work, you need to add `.fluent-modal` class to the outer `.modal` element:

```
 <div class='modal fade fluent-modal' id='modal-example' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='modal-example-title' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-right modal-bottom' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <h5 class='modal-title' id='modal-example-title'>TITLE</h5>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
          <span aria-hidden='true' class='mi mi-Close'></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```